# rss/atom feed for abc.go.com

Tags: rss

I'm wondering if there's an rss feed for show's on [abc.go.com](http://abc.go.com) so I can see when new episodes are uploaded. The 'episode guide' section has one, but it's posted before the episode is uploaded. Asking here because perhaps someone has found something I haven't.

Comment: For all shows or just particular shows?

Comment: @Eight hmmm maybe comments should email me. Just particular shows.

Answer (score 2):

if you can't find the RSS you want on any website, you can always create a custom one yourself with [dapper](http://open.dapper.net/). it's pretty easy to figure out how with their instructions.

Answer (score -1):

Grab the [Most Recent Full Episodes feed](http://cdn.abc.go.com/vp2/ws-supt/s/syndication/2000/rss/001/001/lf/PL5515990/-1/-1/-1/-1) (found at ABC.com > Watch Episodes > Most Recent).

This will give you a feed of all of the episodes uploaded to abc.go.com.

Then you can either delete those that don't interest you or hook up with something like Yahoo! Pipes and create a filter for just the shows you want to be notified about.

Since the raw all shows feed contains the name of the program in the title, you can use that to filter in/out of the cleaned up feed.